# Read Large JSON files (3K+) from S3 and Select Specific Keys from Array

Tags: python, json, pyspark, aws-glue

I need to read from multiple JSON files (3K+), stored in s3, all of which have the same structure.  The structure is very large and nested. Within those files, is an array that contains objects, key:value pairs.  I need to select a few of those keys and write the values out to a PySpark dataframe.  I am using PySpark/Python3 to write the code within AWS Glue.

I have thus far attempted to create a dataframe from the S3 files, and then to infer the schema.  I am not sure if this is correct, nor am I sure if this is the most efficient.  I am also not sure where to take this next to find the "Products" array and extract the few keys from within the array.

```
json_data_frame = spark.read.json("s3://" + args['destinationBucketName'] + "/" + args['s3SourcePath'])

json_schema = spark.read.json(json_data_frame.rdd.map(lambda row: row.json)).schema
```

My desired results are a dataframe that contains the columns, each of which being the keys from the array, and having all the values from the entirety of the s3 files.

EDIT: I made it a little further:

```
json_data_frame = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("s3://" + args['destinationBucketName'] + "/" + args['s3SourcePath'])

final_data_frame_prep = json_data_frame.withColumn("name", json_data_frame["products"].getItem("name")).withColumn("ndc_product_code", json_data_frame["products"].getItem("ndc_product_code"))

final_data_frame = final_data_frame_prep.select("name","ndc_product_code")

final_data_frame.show(20,False)
```

Where I am now the dataframe is creating as I would suspect with the exception that each of the values is a list, some with a single item, some with multiples.  I now need to break out the lists into separate rows.  I would love advice there if you should have any.  Current dataframe:

```
+------------------+----------------------+
|name |ndc_product_code |
+------------------+----------------------+
|[Refludan] |[50419-150] |
|[Erbitux, Erbitux]|[66733-948, 66733-958]|
+------------------+----------------------+
```

EDIT2:

```
json_data_frame = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("s3://" + args['destinationBucketName'] + "/" + args['s3SourcePath'])

final_data_frame_prep = json_data_frame.withColumn("name", explode(json_data_frame["products"].getItem("name"))).withColumn("ndc_product_code", explode(json_data_frame["products"].getItem("ndc_product_code"))).withColumn("dosage_form", explode(json_data_frame["products"].getItem("dosage_form"))).withColumn("strength", explode(json_data_frame["products"].getItem("strength")))

final_data_frame = final_data_frame_prep.select("name","ndc_product_code","dosage_form","strength")

final_data_frame.show(20,False)
```

I was able to add an explode to the code, as well as the remaining two columns, but am seeing duplication in the dataframe, as if the lists are matching all possibilities instead of matching on the object within the array that the keys came from.  The dataframe is now:

```
+--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
|name |ndc_product_code|dosage_form|strength |
+--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
|Refludan|50419-150 |Powder |50 mg/1mL|
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
+--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
```

EDIT3: 
I don't believe the explode is what I want.  I reverted the code back to edit 1.  The table is presenting as

```
+------------------+----------------------+
|name |ndc_product_code |
+------------------+----------------------+
|[Refludan] |[50419-150] |
|[Erbitux, Erbitux]|[66733-948, 66733-958]|
+------------------+----------------------+
```

and what I desire is:

```
+------------------+----------------------+
|name |ndc_product_code |
+------------------+----------------------+
|[Refludan]|[50419-150]|
|[Erbitux]|[66733-948]|
|[Erbitux]|[66733-958]|
+------------------+----------------------+
```

Is there a way to do this, i.e. matching on position in the array and creating new rows based on that?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
+--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
|name |ndc_product_code|dosage_form|strength |
+--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
|Refludan|50419-150 |Powder |50 mg/1mL|
|Erbitux |66733-948 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
|Erbitux |66733-958 |Solution |2 mg/1mL |
+--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
```

The code is:

```
# Read in the json files from s3
json_data_frame = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("s3://" + args['destinationBucketName'] + "/" + args['s3SourcePath'])

final_data_frame_prepprep = json_data_frame.withColumn("products_exp", explode(json_data_frame["products"]))\

final_data_frame_prep = final_data_frame_prepprep.withColumn("name", final_data_frame_prepprep["products_exp"].getItem("name"))\
                                             .withColumn("ndc_product_code", final_data_frame_prepprep["products_exp"].getItem("ndc_product_code"))\
                                             .withColumn("dosage_form", final_data_frame_prepprep["products_exp"].getItem("dosage_form"))\
                                             .withColumn("strength", final_data_frame_prepprep["products_exp"].getItem("strength"))

final_data_frame = final_data_frame_prep.select("name","ndc_product_code","dosage_form","strength")

final_data_frame.show(20,False)
```

The key was to explode the data as a whole, then get the items from the arrays, then select what you want to keep.  I hope this helps someone else--Cheers